# subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW, AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'CREATE_NO_WINDOW'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

When I try to do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'CREATE_NO_WINDOW'
```

Why is this? The subprocess documentation clearly states the following.

```html
subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW¶
A Popen creationflags parameter to specify that a new process will not create a window.

New in version 3.7.
```

I have `python 3.9.5` installed

**EDIT** I am using `Linux Ubuntu 21.04`

Comment: Those are available under MS Windows only.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: The subprocess documentation clearly states that `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` is a Windows constant: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants

Comment: The docs could use a clarifying note that "Windows Constants" means constants for Microsoft Windows, not for a windowed app in general. Its an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Is that default behaviour on Linux then?

Answer (score 1):

These creation flags are only available on a `windows` OS, likely you are on some POSIX variant

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
look in this link ..
you must upgrade your version python to 3.7 if it's old
it's solved to me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).